# How do I merge android resources from different cordova plugins?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I am writing a plugin for cordova-android platform for my app that has other plugins also. When I specify my resources [ strings, drawables etc ] for my plugin , while building for the android platform the resources get overridden in /res folder and the older plugin fails due to non-availability of the resources it needs.

I am using cordova-android@6.4.0

What I want is to merge all the resources from all the plugins and then platform to build.

Comment: I'm using several plugins together and never had such issue... your solution in this case (due to the lack of details you provided) is to rename / move the colliding files from one of the plugins, then re-add the updated plugin. To get help, update the post and add full details of plugins and problematic files dude.